# Как сделать из десятичной дроби соответствующее целое число?

Tags: c++

Мне дали задание найти разницу между сумами целой и дробной части действительного числа. Я смог с помощью оператора `mod.f` разделить число на целую и дробную часть. Для нахождения суммы использую следующий цикл:

```
a1:
    if (k != 0) {

        g = k % 10;
        f = g + f;
        k = k / 10;
        goto a1;
    }
```

С целой частью я справился, но для дробной части это не подходит по понятным причинам. Ну и вот суть проблемы: как мне превратить десятичную дробь в целое число без 0. ?

Comment: А из 0.7500000000000000000001 что надо получить? 7500000000000000000001? Тогда читайте число как строку, убирайте точку и ведущие нули...

Comment: а как потом из строки вернуть в int это число?

Comment: Что бы из дроби сделать целое, надо округлить ее до целых.

Comment: возможно я просто не так вопрос задал, но мне это не подходит

Comment: как я уже написал мне надо что то типа убрать нуль перед точкой и всё, этого будет достаточно.

Comment: ну и чтобы это число в переменную потом сохранить для последующих итераций .

Comment: Навеяно комментарием @Harry https://pastebin.com/9JgVXXXL

Comment: `как например число 0.75 сделать 75` Каким способом задаётся ваше «число»? Если это строка, то просто вырежьте всё после десятичной точки. Если это число с плавающей точкой, то тут нужно уточнять задачу, какие числа могут быть на входе и что ожидается получить на выходе. Например, вещественное число `0.1` типом `double` не представимо. [Пример](https://ideone.com/3OOSDs). Т.е. считав строку `0.1` следующим кодом `double d; cin >> d;`, точное вещественное значение `0.1` в переменной `d` вы не получите.

Comment: а как вырезать  всё после десятичной точки? Я просто совсем зелёный и не очень понимаю как это сделать. Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать цикл который будет умножать десятичную дробь на 10 до тех пор, пока остача от деления не будет 0. Код прилагаеться ` do {
        n * 10;
    } while (n % 10==0);
    cout << n; ` ( если я делаю что-то не так то говорите сразу)

Comment: Если вам нужно взять дробную часть числа, используйте функцию `modf`

Comment: этим я воспользовался, мне дальше нужно использовать дробную часть в следующем цикле a2:
    if (p != 0) {

        h = p % 10;
        b = h + b;
        n = n / 10;
        goto a2;
    }

Comment: Опишите всю задачу целиком, лучше всего отредактируйте свой вопрос, а то так ничего не понятно. Кстати, использование оператора безусловного перехода - плохая практика. Да и приведенный вами "цикл" зациклится навечно.

Comment: @Manukafool рассмотрите пример по ссылке которую я скинул выше. Как раз там и получается из 0.75 то самое 75 что вы хотите.

Comment: Я верю что это правильно, но я на данный момент не встречался з массивами и наш преподаватель ни слова о них не сказал, так что может есть ещё какие-то варианты?

Comment: Дробная часть, взятая от числа с помощью `modf`, не обязательно равна дробной части, выделенной из **исходного** числа в строковом представлении, так что первый совет от Harry наиболее полезен. Какова, кстати, **точная** формулировка задания?

Comment: Ну формулировку я вроде точную написал, и если то что предложил пользователь Harry верно, то пожалуйста , можете мне это показать в виде кода, я просто не до конца понимаю как это сделать.

Comment: Ну с учетом отредактированного вопроса: считывайте вводимое число как строку, разбейте на две подстроки, относительно точки, преобразуйте полученные подстроки в числа, эти числа передавайте в ваш цикл. Или, что более правильно: используйте итератор для прохода по строке и подсчета сумм цифр.

Comment: Пожалуйста, если вам не трудно, напишите это в виде кода, просто я не понимаю как это писать и как это работает, простите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа

```
int s2i(string& s)
{
    if (auto p = s.find('.'); p != s.npos)
        s.erase(p,1);
    return stoi(s);
}
```

устроит? Защиту от дурака можно и дописать, как и для научной записи (эта функция не поймет что-то типа `1e3`).

Comment: это устроит, но я не понимаю что делает s2i, и что такое stoi(s).

Comment: ой, я понял что такое s2i

Comment: но что такое stoi(s) я всё равно не понял, объяните пожалуйста

Comment: Я уже понял, спасибо большое!